# react-native-tesseract-ocr where to place the tessdata file

Tags: react-native, tesseract

I'm following the instructions from the official npm home page of the library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tesseract-ocr and it says

> Don't forget to ...
>   add v3.04 trained data files to the appropriate folder

But I'm not entirely sure where I'm supposed to place the tessdata file inside my react-native project. Is anyone familiar with this library?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr/tree/patch-1#mostly-automatic-installation) though these ones were a little hard to [find](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr/issues/8#issuecomment-349500514)

> Download Trained data [v3.04 Trained data files](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00)
>
> - iOS: Drag and drop the
>     `tessdata` into your project at root in xCode. Select `Copy items if
>     needed` and `Copy folder reference`
> - Android: It must be extracted in
>     `android/app/src/main/assets/tessdata`.

Though I am not 100% sure these are correct as these instructions are on a different branch than the master.  I am also not sure that this repo is that regularly maintained. There were some [updates](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr/commits/master) in January 2019, but the last ones before that were March 2018.

Comment: yeah it feels like an abandoned library, I need to find ocr library that I can run on react-native and that's the only one I found...I'm facing this issue https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr/issues/47 and I thought it was because I missplaced the train data but I haven't :(